# Why don't humans use animals after they die naturally?

Tags: commercial-farming

Humans use animals for eating, clothes, fashion, etc., all of which is obviously wrong.

Why don't they eat them after they die naturally of old age? Why don't they use their fur, or skin after they die of naturally?

Thank You.

Comment: Are you asking "Why do farmers slaughter animals instead of keeping them until they die naturally?"

Comment: See also: [Dealing with natural deaths of animals](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/1358/89)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I won't talk about "product quality" since it will probably highly vary from one place to another.

That being said, price is probably a leading factor.

Most animals that are bred for leather, meat, etc... live far shorter than their natural lifespan. The cost of feeding and caring for the animal over time is factored into the cost of animal products. As soon as the maximum profit can be made from the profits of slaughter, the animal is killed.

EDIT to come : few numbers once I got the time to find international sources.

Comment: Thank you @Edelk sir/mam. So what I am learning nowadays is that money (non-living) is of much greater value/worth than a living being's life.

Answer (score 7):

The meat is less tasty. Notice how carnivore humans not only eat animals; they eat child animals. Lamb, veal, etc. The same is probably true for the quality of fur or leather. However, down can be produced entirely by harvesting naturally lost feathers

And, of course, it's much cheaper to feed an animal for one year than for five years.

Answer (score 3):

Humans do use animals that died of natural causes. This still occurs in many cultures and there is plenty of anthropological, archaeological, and molecular evidence that we were scavengers as well and hunter-gatherers during our evolutionary and even recent history. Many indigenous people still live off the land all over the world and often a key component of their values and beliefs is the inherent value of lives including animals. There are many cultural practices in which as many parts of the animal is used to reduce waste.

The main reason that this no longer occurs widely would likely be yield. As the population has soared, there’s been an increasing need to industrialise. This has especially been important with plant products and food crops with the need to provide food such as staple crops to feed a growing population. It also occurs with animals. We simply cannot find enough plant or animal products by scavenging (or even hunting) to meet the demand of our society.

The main reason that we have selectively bred domesticated crops and animals is to meet this demand. Many domesticated species are still used in favour or higher quality or more desirable varieties (in other traits) because the exisiting farmed varieties have been bred for centuries to provide higher yields. This is why particular strains are farmed while others are not and are still less desirable when the die of natural causes, even if the quality isn’t compromised (in the case tough meat in old age or roadkill).

This most notably occurs in plant survives such as the larger seeds in wheat, corn, and fruits. These produce larger food crops which are more durable during transport or storage. It also occurs in livestock where domesticated species produce far higher yields of wool and milk or grow faster, have higher fecundity (twins or larger litters), and grow more flesh for meat yields.

There’s also the “cringe” factor. Many people would not use their deceased pets to make food or clothing for example. Similarly, people in industrialised societies (with better options) would usually not consume roadkill unless in extreme poverty or starvation.

Answer (score 2):

A farmer that would use these practices could not compete economically with a farmer that used current practices. Other farmers would be able to sell their product so much cheaper that your hypothetical kind farmer would starve to death.  There is a financial incentive for cruelty.